# Read block of data into matlab array

Tags: matlab

I have a data file look like the following

```
3 1.0 1.4 1.7
2 1.2 1.5
1 1.1
2 1.1 1.2
```

For each line, the first integer indicates the number of floating numbers in this line.

Now I want to load all the data into a single matlab array, and ignore first column, that is, I want to get a array like this

```
>>arr = [1.0, 1.4, 1.7, 1.2, 1.5, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2]
```

if for each line, we have same number of floating numbers, I can simply do it like this

```
>>arr = load datafile ;
>>arr = arr(:,2:end) ; %ignore the first column
>>arr = arr(:) ;
```

However, if we have different number of floating numbers in each line, it seems we cannot directly loaded the file into a matrix. Is there any simple way to accomplish this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's read the numbers as strings:

```
C = textread('myfile.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
```

The result is a cell-array of strings, so let's apply `str2num` on each cell to obtain numerical values:

```
C = cellfun(@str2num, C, 'Uniform', false);
```

Now let's discard the first element from each cell:

```
C = cellfun(@(x)x(2:end), C, 'Uniform', false);
```

Finally, we concatenate all values into one vector:

```
arr = [C{:}]
```

This is the complete code:

```
C = textread('test.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); %// Read data
C = cellfun(@str2num, C, 'Uniform', false);        %// Convert to numbers
C = cellfun(@(x)x(2:end), C, 'Uniform', false);    %// Remove first values
arr = [C{:}]

arr = 
    1.0000    1.4000    1.7000    1.2000    1.5000    1.1000    1.1000    1.2000
```

Comment: Thank you, EitanT, This is a nice way to parse the file. textread seems a bit like Python's open(somefile).readlines() or open(somefile).read().split(some delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to just read the file line by line

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
arr = [];
tline = fgetl(fid);
while (tline ~= -1)
    temp = str2num(tline);
    arr = [arr temp(2:end)];
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

You might also try using the [loadcell](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1965) function, though I didn't try it so I'm not positive it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, ioums, though this solution looks a bit C-style