# Matlab - read file with varying line lengths

Tags: matlab, nan, text-processing

I have a data file with varying amount of data per line that I would like to load into Matlab as an array. As an example, suppose the data file looks like

```
1 2
3 4 5 6
7
8 9 10
```

I want to read it into Matlab as an array that looks like

```
1  2  nan nan
3  4   5   6
7 nan nan nan
8  9  10  nan
```

I can do this by doing a for loop over all lines of the file but my files are very large and I am looking for an efficient solution. Any ideas would be highly appreciated. If it helps, I also know an upper bound on the maximum line length across the file.

Comment: you can us `textread`

Comment: Yes you should take a look at the example shown here close to what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158165/read-block-of-data-into-matlab-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Divakar's answer works if you don't have any values of zero in your text file, that's may not generally be the case. For example, if your text array was

```
1 2 3
4 0
5 6 0 7 8
```

then Divakar's result would be:

```
1 2 3 nan nan
4 nan nan nan nan
5 6 nan 7 8
```

whereas you really want:

```
1 2 3 nan nan
4 0 nan nan nan
5 6 0 7 8
```

The easiest way to implement this is to open up the dlmread function (just type dlmread into the text editor and press Ctrl+D to open it up). Make sure to save this file as a separate file in the directory you're working in with a different name (i.e. dlmread_nan.m).

Go down to this part of the code (line 126 in my version):

```
if isempty(delimiter)
    result  = textscan(fid,'',nrows,'headerlines',r,'headercolumns',c,...
                       'returnonerror',0,'emptyvalue',0, 'CollectOutput', true);
else
    delimiter = sprintf(delimiter);
    whitespace  = setdiff(sprintf(' \b\t'),delimiter);
    result  = textscan(fid,'',nrows,...
                   'delimiter',delimiter,'whitespace',whitespace, ...
                   'headerlines',r,'headercolumns',c,...
                   'returnonerror',0,'emptyvalue',0,'CollectOutput', true);
end
```

and change the value after 'emptyvalue' in both cases to NaN instead of 0. Save the file. It should look like this:

```
if isempty(delimiter)
    result  = textscan(fid,'',nrows,'headerlines',r,'headercolumns',c,...
                       'returnonerror',0,'emptyvalue',NaN, 'CollectOutput', true);
else
    delimiter = sprintf(delimiter);
    whitespace  = setdiff(sprintf(' \b\t'),delimiter);
    result  = textscan(fid,'',nrows,...
                   'delimiter',delimiter,'whitespace',whitespace, ...
                   'headerlines',r,'headercolumns',c,...
                   'returnonerror',0,'emptyvalue',NaN,'CollectOutput', true);
end
```

To get your array, use this:

```
result = dlmread_nan('text.txt', ' '); 
%%//This will give you exactly what you're looking for.
```

It's a little cumbersome, but by copying from MATLAB's library, it'll probably be a lot more robust and error-free than writing it from scratch yourself.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer where you are referencing my solution, as I have added solution for the case when data has zeros :)

Answer (score 2):

## **Case 1: Data with no zeros**

This technique uses **[`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)** that inherently converts the empty places to zeros and then we need to convert those to NaNs as needed to obtain the desired output.

**Code**

```
out = dlmread(textfile_path, ' ') %%// textfile_path is path to your text file
out(out==0)=NaN %%// out is your desired output
```

**Input**

```
1 2
3 4 5 6
7
8 9 10
```

**Output**

```
out =
     1     2   NaN   NaN
     3     4     5     6
     7   NaN   NaN   NaN
     8     9    10   NaN
```

## **Case 2: Data with zeros and thus warrantes extra care to preserve those zeros**

This approach revolves around importing data using **[`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)** to column arrays of cells that preserves zeros as they are and makes the empty places as NaNs. The only issue is that for the final line, because of the absence of any empty places (if the last line isn't the longest one), the length isn't equal to the number of lines. For the same, we need few extra lines of codes.

**Approach 1:**

**Code**

```
fid = fopen(textfile_path,'r');  %%// textfile_path is path to your text file
data1 = textscan(fid,'');
fclose(fid);

lens = cellfun(@numel,data1)
out = NaN(max(lens),numel(lens))  %%// out will be your output
for k = 1:numel(lens)
    out(1:lens(k),k) = data1{:,k}
end
```

**Approach 2 (Shorter version):**

**Code**

```
fid = fopen(textfile_path,'r');  %%// textfile_path is path to your text file
data1 = textscan(fid,'');
fclose(fid);

n1 = find(diff(cellfun(@numel,data1))~=0)

%%// out will be your output
out = [horzcat(data1{:,[1 n1]}) [horzcat(data1{:,[n1+1:end]}) ; NaN(1,numel(data1)-n1)]]
```

**Input**

```
1 2 3
4 0
5 6 0 7 8
0 0
```

**Output**

```
out =
     1     2     3   NaN   NaN
     4     0   NaN   NaN   NaN
     5     6     0     7     8
     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. textread sufficed for my purposes but I will bookmark this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In This case?

**Input**

```
1 2 3   6
4   5
1   0 7 8
0 0     5
```

How to do?

Textscan will be dangerous because it will not preserve the number position