# MATLAB - How to save vectors with different length

Tags: matlab, file, vector

I created a file that contains vectors and these could have empty space between their elements.

```
-77.4  1   0.17    260     88 1004.0 1006.5 
-77.3  1   0.17               1009.2 1011.8
```

I save the file **'myfile.txt'** row by row with **fprintf()** function.

Well, when I load the file with the command **load('myfile.txt')** I receive this error message "Number of columns on line ... must be the same as previous lines"

How can I fix it? Perhaps save the row vectors by another way? How to do?

Thank you

Comment: use the `save` command to save .mat files.

Comment: If you need to save as text, use a separator other than space, for example a comma. That may help when reading the file

Comment: if you are okay saving the empty places as NaNs, look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552162/matlab-read-file-with-varying-line-lengths)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I save the entire vector as a line and I can't put separator

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off by using the `save` command as @maxywb stated in his comment, but if you find yourself in a situation where you  have a text file that does not have consistent column numbers, you can parse the file line by line and save the results into a cell array

```
fid = fopen('myFile.txt','r');
values = {};
count = 1;
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    values{count} = textscan(tline,'%f','delimiter',', ');
    count = count+1;
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: OK thank you, it might be a good solution but I should to create a new file that contains the cell values (as you suggest) If I could to create a new "myFile.txt" how do you think is better to do? I would to save row by row (not single values)